# In Test Explorer of Visual Studio 2013, how can I show tests in a table view like VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, test-explorer

In Test Explorer of Visual Studio 2013, I want to show tests in a table with columns like 'Description', 'Project'. It is easy to add/remove those columns in VS2010. How can I do it in VS2013?